# PHP & Array: count distance between two keys

Tags: php, arrays, pointers, count, position

Having an array similar to the one below:

```
$steps = array(0 => 'aaa', 1 => 'bbb', 2 => 'ccc', ......, 7 => 'hhh', 8 => 'iii', .....);
```

How can I calculate how many steps (key) do I need to reach key 2 from key 7 respecting the sequence?

Comment: Perhaps simply `7-2`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have numeric keys that never have any missing numbers, you can use basic subtraction.

If you need to account for possible missing numbers, or the keys are not numeric, you can use a combination of `array_keys()` and `array_search()`:

```
$array = array(
    0 => 'aaa',
    1 => 'bbb',
    3 => 'ccc',
    'four' => 'ddd',
    900 => 'eee',
    13 => 'fff'
);

$from = 1;
$to = 900;

$keys = array_keys($array);

$from_index = array_search($from, $keys); // 1
$to_index = array_search($to, $keys); // 4

$steps = $to_index - $from_index;
// 3 steps: from 1-3, from 3-'four' and from 'four'-900
```

Comment: I thank you for the answers but I do not have to leave from key 2 but from key 7, in the right direction of the array, and then start from index 0 once the end of the array is reached.

Is it impossible as reasoning or is it just twisted?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by writing this code:

```
$tot_step = 0;

$steps = array(
    0 => 'aaa',
    1 => 'bbb',
    2 => 'ccc',
    3 => 'ddd',
    4 => 'eee',
    5 => 'fff',
    6 => 'ggg',
    7 => 'hhh',
    8 => 'iii',
    9 => 'jjj',
    10 => 'aaa'
);

$from = "ddd";
$to = "bbb";

$from_index = array_search($from, $steps);
$to_index = array_search($to, $steps);

$last = $steps[(count($steps)-1)];

if ($from_index > 0) {

    if ($to == $last)
        $to_index = (count($steps)-1);

    $arr_l = count($steps);
    $mila = array();

    for ($ind = $from_index; $ind <= ($arr_l-1); $ind++) {

        if ($to == $last) {

            if ($steps[$ind] != $last)
                $mila[] = $steps[$ind];

        } else {

            $mila[] = $steps[$ind];

        }

        unset($steps[$ind]);

    }

    if (!empty($mila)) {

        for ($i = (count($mila)-1); $i >= 0; $i--)
            array_unshift($steps, $mila[$i]);

    }

    $to_new = array_search($to, $steps);

    foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == $to_new)
            break;
        else
            $tot_step++;

    }


} elseif ($from_index == 0) {

    if ($to_index == $from_index) {

        $tot_step = (count($steps)-1);

    } else {

        foreach ($steps as $key => $value) {

            if ($key == $to_index)
                break;
            else
                $tot_step++;

        }

    }

}

echo $tot_step;
```

I hope it will be useful to someone